# Why is $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ an irreducible lattice in $SL(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

It is a well-known fact $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ a lattice in $SL(n,\mathbb R)$. The definition of an irreducible lattice can be found in the following Wikipedia link:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)#Irreducibility

I wonder how to show that $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ is indeed an irreducible lattice $SL(n,\mathbb R)$. Namely the intersection of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ with any factor of $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ is either dense (unlikely I think) or not a lattice.

Comment: $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has no nontrivial product decompositions so isn't every lattice irreducible by this definition?

Comment: Actually I don't know the fact that SL_n(R) has no nontrivial product decompositions. Do you think you can write an answer? @qiaochuyuan

Comment: It follows from the fact that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is simple, so has no nontrivial product decompositions either.